# Default selected option: Undefined index

Tags: html, select, menu

I'm actually trying to load a html site. 
I have a select menu and there's an option selected by default, but I got this error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: country_select in C:\xampp\htdocs\herramientaSPEND\generalSpend.php on line 5
```

but the select menu is blank.

line 5:

```
<?php 
    $country = $_POST['country_select']; 
?>
```

---

Here's my code:

```
<table id="option-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="info text-center header-table">
          Pais
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select class="custom-select" data-width "75px" name="country_select" id="pais" onchange="this.form.submit();">
            <option value="Regional" selected>Regional</option>
            <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
            <option value="Brazil">Brazil</option>
            <option value="Dominican R.">Dominicana</option>
            <option value="El Salvador">El Salvador</option>
            <option value="Guatemala">Guatemala</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

(just in case... later on I'm using a MySQL query, I'm not sure if it changes something)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can I Have a look at this: C:\xampp\htdocs\herramientaSPEND\generalSpend.php on line 5

Comment: Sure!!!

its `<?php   $country = $_POST['country_select'];   ?>`